# What are some good practices on handling 'resource not found'-errors in a REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I have the follwing link:
`/api/v1/m/projects/{p_id}/sprints/{s_id}/tasks/{t_id}`

If a user calls this link I want to send an error message if the resourse is not found (the message depends on resource - project or sprint or task).

Is this right way to search all resources in turns?

1. Search project by id, if null throw exception and send error message.
2. Search sprints by id and by project, if null ...
3. And then search task by project, sprint and id.

Comment: I would use spring dsl , it's well documented in spring, and your URL will link will be /api/v1/m?project={p_id}&sprint={s_id}&task={t_id}

Comment: But I need to use this link.

Comment: In that case you can build predicate and customize to use dsl using given inputs in URL .

Comment: Ok, but i woun't know wich resource is not found.
I want to send error message with name of resource. 
Now, I have one solution - search one by one.

Comment: Correct you have to handle one by one and handle exceptions and throw appropriate message.

Comment: Rephrased as question and fixed some grammar.